# Should the head noun be plural or singular in "the development(s) of these theories"

Tags: grammatical-number, noun-phrases, of-phrases

What number should the head noun have in a noun phrase complemented by an *of*-phrase, where the NP complement of *of* is headed by a plural noun? Examples:

*the development(s) of these theories*

*the front door(s) of the houses*

*the ear(s) of the teacups*

(I'm assuming here that each individual theory/house/teacup has only one development/front door/ear each).

Is there a rule here, or do we just decide which number to use from one context to another? In that case, based on what?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you refer to ears of teacups, you mean the handles.

Front doors and handles are countable nouns, and there are multiple houses/teacups and usually one front door/handle for each house/teacup. This means that there are multiple doors and handles, so you use a plural.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/development), development with the meaning "the process of developing something new" is uncountable, so it would be singular in your first sentence. Note that there are other meanings of development that are countable, but the meaning is not applicable to this sentence.

Comment: when you see "the handles of the cups", how can you tell how many handles each cup has?

Comment: Right, so plural if the noun is countable. Thank you :) This does beg the question brought up by @AndrewTobilko though...

Comment: And yes – I did mean the handle; you do use "ear" for this as well, don't you?

Comment: @Hannah I have never heard anybody refer to a teacup handle as an ear. The reverse sometimes happens though: a person whose ears stick out sideways is said to have "jug ears", like the handles of a jug. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jug_ears

Comment: @AndrewTobilko it's not "the cups" but "the teacups" and I have never seen a teacup with more than one handle. Other types of cups do have no handle, and some have two handles- for example trophies like the FA cup and (sometimes) the F1 cup, and a Tommee Tippee cup. I have updated my answer anyway, to add the word "usually".

Comment: Thanks again JavaLatte :) I guess it's just transfer from my own language then (calling  the handle of a tea cup its ear, I mean). As for the ambiguity in number brought up by @AndrewTobilko I guess you're right that tea cups generally have just one handle, but it doesn't change that there is an inherent ambiguity here. I guess that's what made me ask the question in the first place, thinking that number might be determined by whether each instance of the relevant noun has one or several handles or whatever :)

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks! Let's consider 2-handled (double-handled) teacups (I guess they are more common in the East). And let's say the right handle of any given teacup has a defect or coloured differently. Now I would like to refer to them both collectively (the right handles of the teacups are defective) and individually (the right handle of the teacups is red). Does it make sense or should the plural be used in both cases?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko You would use the plural in both of the examples that you quoted, so it should be "the right handles of the teacups are red". if you wanted to refer to the handles teacups/handles individually, you would say "the right handle of each teacup is red" or "the right handle of every teacup is red".